# Uber-API iOS Swift unable to find current location

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I have been working with the example **Uber API** at https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/tree/master/examples/Swift%20SDK/Swift%20SDK . I am using localhost and have the app pulling through except user location.

I keep getting the error:"`Unable able to find current location`"

[image]

Any suggestions where to start? I have added the **CoreLocation.framework** and tried modifying the `RideRequestWidgetExampleViewController`. I am in UberSandBox still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to make sure that your simulator location is enabled. When you open the simulator if you go to **Debug > Location**  is the **None** option checked?

Otherwise, make sure that you add either the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` keys to your Info.plist with a string describing why you need location

Comment: Thanks John -  it seems to be the first issue but my current location is now working to a degree today.  My simulator was set to a custom location for a long and lat that is on 1800 Ellis Street in San Francisco.  It seems to be pulling this in from the DeeplinkExampleViewController. I have been able to set the Simulator to custom, none, and Apple and it still goes to this location. The NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key is in the InfoPlist with a reason. I will dig into the DeeplinkExampleViewController.

Comment: It is also in the AuthorizationCodeGrantExampleViewController

Comment: One more correction - I realized I need to close the project before changing the Simulator. If at none, I get the original message "Unable ...". If at custom, it goes the 1800 address. If at Apple, I get message "2 Infinite Loop"